# Intermittent 500 Error when connecting to Amazon S3 server

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-mvc-3

I am connecting to Amazon S3 server through the dll for uploading and downloading.

I get a error as "Could not connect to host 187.6.78.8:443".
Sometimes it connects and sometimes it doesnt.

What could be the reason?What is the solution for this?

Comment: It simply means that it could not connect to tcp/IP end point, your network is overloaded or timed out.

Comment: So,what can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: If it is on shared server, you have to move on to dedicated server, or buy bigger bandwidth line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your firewall settings, if it is blocking to connect with the amazon server.